# Plotly Value error - Invalid property for colour

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have been experiencing errors while generating charts using Plotly and it seems to be affecting most of the charts I try producing on it. The error also seems to be a duplicate across all the failures. I am using Jupyter notebook (Anaconda 3, Python 3.6).

Code that fails to generate output is found below (but my data table and everything else is correct).

** I am unsure if there's some problem with the Plotly library (I'm using Plotly's latest that I installed using "Pip install Plotly")

```
import pandas as pd # package for high-performance, easy-to-use data 
structures and data analysis
import numpy as np # fundamental package for scientific computing with Python
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting
import seaborn as sns # for making plots with seaborn
color = sns.color_palette()
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
offline.init_notebook_mode()
from plotly import tools
import plotly.tools as tls
import squarify

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from numpy import array
from matplotlib import cm

# import cufflinks and offline mode
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

# from sklearn import preprocessing
# # Supress unnecessary warnings so that presentation looks clean
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# # Print all rows and columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

*************************************************
temp = application_train["TARGET"].value_counts()
df = pd.DataFrame({'labels': temp.index,
               'values': temp.values
              })
df.iplot(kind='scatter',labels='labels',values='values', title='Loan 
Repayed or not')
```

### ERROR LOG (Below)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-2c9a8a530884> in <module>()
  3                    'values': temp.values
  4                   })
----> 5 df.iplot(kind='scatter',labels='labels',values='values', title='Loan 
Repayed or not')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py in 
_iplot(self, data, layout, filename, sharing, kind, title, xTitle, yTitle, 
zTitle, theme, colors, colorscale, fill, width, dash, mode, symbol, size, 
barmode, sortbars, bargap, bargroupgap, bins, histnorm, histfunc, 
orientation, 
boxpoints, annotations, keys, bestfit, bestfit_colors, mean, mean_colors, 
categories, x, y, z, text, gridcolor, zerolinecolor, margin, labels, values, 
secondary_y, secondary_y_title, subplots, shape, error_x, error_y, 
error_type, 
locations, lon, lat, asFrame, asDates, asFigure, asImage, dimensions, asPlot, 
asUrl, online, **kwargs)
698                                                                 
bargap=bargap,bargroupgap=bargroupgap,
annotations=annotations,gridcolor=gridcolor 
,
699                                                            
dimensions=dimensions,
--> 700                                  
zerolinecolor=zerolinecolor,margin=margin,is3d='3d' in kind,**l_kwargs)
701 
702         if not data:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\tools.py in 
getLayout(kind, 
theme, title, xTitle, yTitle, zTitle, barmode, bargap, bargroupgap, margin, 
dimensions, width, height, annotations, is3d, **kwargs)
197 
198         theme_data = getTheme(theme)
--> 199         layout=Layout(theme_data['layout'])
200         layout['xaxis1'].update({'title':xTitle})
201         layout['yaxis1'].update({'title':yTitle})

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_layout.py in 
__init__(self, arg, angularaxis, annotations, autosize, bargap, bargroupgap, 
barmode, barnorm, boxgap, boxgroupgap, boxmode, calendar, colorway, 
datarevision, 
direction, dragmode, font, geo, grid, height, hiddenlabels, hiddenlabelssrc, 
hidesources, hoverdistance, hoverlabel, hovermode, images, legend, mapbox, 
margin, orientation, paper_bgcolor, plot_bgcolor, polar, radialaxis, scene, 
selectdirection, separators, shapes, showlegend, sliders, spikedistance, 
template, ternary, title, titlefont, updatemenus, violingap, violingroupgap, 
violinmode, width, xaxis, yaxis, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
__setattr__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
__setattr__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_layout.py in 
legend(self, val)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
__setitem__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
__setitem__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
_set_compound_prop(self, prop, val)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in 
validate_coerce(self, v)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\plotly\graph_objs\layout\_legend.py in 
__init__(self, arg, bgcolor, bordercolor, borderwidth, font, orientation, 
tracegroupgap, traceorder, x, xanchor, y, yanchor, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
__setattr__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\plotly\graph_objs\layout\_legend.py in 
bgcolor(self, val)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
__setitem__(self, prop, value)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in 
_set_prop(self, prop, val)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in 
validate_coerce(self, v, should_raise)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_plotly_utils\basevalidators.py in 
raise_invalid_val(self, v)

ValueError: 
Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'bgcolor' property of 
layout.legend
    Received value: 'pearl02'

The 'bgcolor' property is a color and may be specified as:
  - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
  - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
  - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
  - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
  - A named CSS color:
        aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
        beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
        blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
        chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue,
        cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan,
        darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgrey, darkgreen,
        darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange,
        darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen,
        darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey,
        darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue,
        dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick,
        floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro,
        ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green,
        greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo,
        ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen,
        lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan,
        lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgrey,
        lightgreen, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen,
        lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey,
        lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen,
        linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine,
        mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple,
        mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen,
        mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue,
        mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy,
        oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered,
        orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise,
        palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink,
        plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown,
        royalblue, saddlebrown, salmon, sandybrown,
        seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver, skyblue,
        slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow, springgreen,
        steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato, turquoise,
        violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke, yellow,
        yellowgreen
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**

After further looking into the issue, the problem is with the cufflinks internal files. Cufflinks is having compatibility issues with the plotly latest version, which is dicussed in this [`Github Issue`](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/119), You could try either downgrading to `plotly 2.7' using the below commands. So that these errors can be eliminated.

```
pip uninstall plotly
pip install plotly==2.7.0
```

---

As you can see in the logs, please refer the below line, which tells us the actual problem.

`--> 199         layout=Layout(theme_data['layout'])`

The error thrown for that lines is.

```
ValueError: 
Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'bgcolor' property of 
layout.legend
    Received value: 'pearl02'

The 'bgcolor' property is a color and may be specified as:
  - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
  - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
  - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
  - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
  - A named CSS color:
        aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure...
```

So you need to change the `layout` object's `bgcolor` property to something other than `pearl02`, which seems to be the issue, You could change the layout object property as.

```
layout = {
    'bgcolor': '#ffffff'
}
```

Please use the below reference link to know about the different ways of setting color values.

1. [Web Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)

Comment: Could you please specify in what file I can update the layout = {'bgcolor' : '#ffffff'}?

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2019 this will get you up and running.   Install cufflinks 0.13.0 with...

```
conda install -c conda-forge cufflinks-py
```

then install/downgrade plotly  to 2.7.0 with ...

```
conda install plotly=2.7.0
```

Cufflinks guys have been working on the fix for sometime, but it's yet to emerge.  Big job apparently.

Comment: I tried the Plotly Version 4 migration guide (https://plot.ly/python/v4-migration/), but ran into a host of other issues. This solution, whilst it is not ideal in terms of downgrading, does work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After R&D found this solution

Just search **cufflinks** folder in your C Drive. You will get **.config**  file in the folder. Open the file in notepad. Change the theme to "solar" ("theme": "solar")

Error will be resolved

Comment: I'm not able to find a .config file in my cufflinks folder